# How to write $3-a-b-c$ in Schur-SOS form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> For positive numbers $a$, $b$, $c$ satisfying $a^3+b^3+c^3=3$, write $3-a-b-c$ as
> \[m(a-b)^2+n(c-a)(c-b),\]
> where $m$, $n$ are rational algebraic expressions containing $a$, $b$, $c$, so that $m$ and $n$ can be proven to be non negative.

I met this problem while I was trying to exert the Schur-SOS method to solve non homogeneous inequality problems that can't be easily homogenized.

To me, it seems like we need to find $m$, $n$ for which $a^3+b^3+c^3-3$ is a factor of $m(a-b)^2+n(c-a)(c-b)$, but I don't know whether this is possible or how to do it.

Comment: Did you start a new account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$3-a-b-c=\frac{27-(a+b+c)^3}{9+3(a+b+c)+(a+b+c)^2}=\frac{9(a^3+b^3+c^3)-(a+b+c)^3}{9+3(a+b+c)+(a+b+c)^2}=$$
$$=\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(8a^3-3a^2b-3a^2c-2abc)}{9+3(a+b+c)+(a+b+c)^2}=\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(8a^3-8abc-3a^2b-3a^2c+6abc)}{9+3(a+b+c)+(a+b+c)^2}=$$
$$=\frac{8(a+b+c)((a-b)^2+(a-c)(b-c))-3(2c(a-b)^2+(a+b)(a-c)(b-c))}{9+3(a+b+c)+(a+b+c)^2}=$$
$$=\frac{(8a+8b+2c)(a-b)^2+(5a+5b+8c)(a-c)(b-c)}{9+3(a+b+c)+(a+b+c)^2}.$$